# backdoor infection scanning (some PID not showing)

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, netstat

I am trying to scan the connections established on my Windows 10 PC.

I'm using the command (as admin) `netstat -ano`. It is working, and I am seeing some established connections.

But when I'm looking for the PID of this established connection in the Task Manager, some of the PIDs are not showing up there.

For example, an established connection is present and having a PID of 2760 when I check the Task manager I do not see the PID 2760.

Can someone explain why and provide some further help? And if someone has some other recommendations to scan the PC that would be great (no external software please.)

Comment: *no external software please* - so, just windows defender then

Comment: This is not possible. Order the Task Manager tab of Details by clicking on the PID column header. If the netstat list is refreshed and the PID is still there, it will be in the Task Manager.

Comment: *no external software please* why indeed? Care to explain? Let's say you do have some infection, why would you mind finding/cleaning it with an external software? There are many scenarios where only external software will be able to do that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Task Manager running as Administrator? If not, it would be missing some processes.

A possibility may be that the process closes quickly, so by the time you look in the Task Manager it is already gone (when you go run again `netstat` does it still show the open connection?)

But a good start would be to run `netstat` also with the `-b` switch, which will display ***the executable involved in creating each connection or listening port***, so you'll have the executable name as well:

```
netstat -anob
```

You can also try to look for the PID in command line using something like:

```
tasklist | findstr /c:"2760"
```